# Detailed place information from google maps api

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to find information on local restaurants from the google maps api, but I cannot seem to find the type of the restaurant (for example, Indian, East African, or American). The information appears in the search box for google maps, but I cannot seem to access it from the api.

This is the api request I made:

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJHTqRbFoZ9ocRhsCg3C_bTtM&key={Redacted}](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJHTqRbFoZ9ocRhsCg3C_bTtM&key=%7BRedacted%7D)

I can get other information like user reviews, and business times, but I cannot seem to get the type of cuisine of the restaurant.
restaurant

[East african restaurant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR6XW.png)